# How do I address dynamic variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic

I get a different number of lists on pages, like

```
list0=[1,2,3,4];
list1=[a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

I can count the number of lists. But how can I use/address "listX" with the different occuring numbers? For example

```
for (let i=0; 1 < 5; i++) {console.log(listX[2)};
```

Hopefully I made myself clear. Thanks in advance!

Couldn't find anything through my favorite web-search-engine. Or put in the wrong question...

Comment: As that linked question's answers indicate, the feeling that you need to do this is a definite sign that you've made a code design mistake.